# Can't run sample code of tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to install tensorflow-gpu, I follow the instruction at 
https://nitishmutha.github.io/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html

everything seems work fine until i import tensorflow

Here is my computer configure:
Windows10
Anaconda 3.4.1.1
Python 3.5.2
Nvidia driver 381.90
Nvidia Gpu Computing Toolkit v8.0
cudnn 8.0

I'm trying to solve it for hours, can anyone give me some hints. Thank you very much

```
C:\Users\kaich>activate tensorflow-gpu

(tensorflow-gpu) C:\Users\kaich>python
Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模組。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模組。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\kaich\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

After giving `activate tensorflow-gpu` execute the following command in the shell.

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: it is not solved

the same error message, I'm using 1080ti, but when i install it, the cuda toolkit seems cannot recognize it, would it related to the problem i'm facing?

Comment: make sure your GPU is cuda compatible one or else it wont work.

Comment: thank you everyone, i solved the problem, as i installed visual community 2017 but not 2015 which i think is compatible. the tensorflow-gpu is installed!

but i encounter another problem posted here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835082/tensorflow-gpu-installed-but-not-used-for-calculation