# tensorflow-gpu installed but not used for calculation

Tags: tensorflow

I have a fresh install of windows 10 and installed tensorflow-gpu (i think i should have done successfully) as i run the sample code, i see the gpu0 is used as follow:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> # Creates a graph.
... a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
>>> b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
>>> c = tf.matmul(a, b)
>>> # Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
... sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
2017-05-08 02:10:35.354149: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-08 02:10:35.354283: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-08 02:10:35.355376: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-08 02:10:35.355835: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-08 02:10:35.356245: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-08 02:10:35.356629: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-08 02:10:35.356977: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-08 02:10:35.357376: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-08 02:10:35.765058: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.607
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 11.00GiB
Free memory: 9.12GiB
2017-05-08 02:10:35.765151: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0
2017-05-08 02:10:35.765851: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y
2017-05-08 02:10:35.780335: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0
2017-05-08 02:10:36.157808: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:257] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0

>>> # Runs the op.
... print(sess.run(c))
MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
2017-05-08 02:10:46.297244: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:841] MatMul: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
2017-05-08 02:10:46.299024: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:841] b: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
2017-05-08 02:10:46.302386: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:841] a: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
```

But when i run the code for deep-learning, the gpu-memory is all used but the gpu-loading is almost 0. the cpu-loading is around 20% (before install tensorflow-gpu, the cpu-loading is 100%), the time for learning is a bit faster than using cpu.

what may be the cause? Please give me some advance, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The line gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0
shows that the computation is being done on the gpu. 
The reason the useage isn't too high is probably because there isn't too much processing to do relative to the power of your GPU.

Comment: but the time for calculation is >2000 second, so i expect it should have a lot of data / process for the gpu to run?

Comment: I assume you mean 2000 milli seconds/2 seconds. The reason is that the data is being shifted from the cpu to gpu and then after the gpu computes the result, it is sent back to the cpu. To see more benefits from the gpu, I suggest using a larger dataset and comparing cpu and gpu speeds/loads.

Comment: @Sohaib-Arift, thank for your help, I'm just a beginner, the problem I'm facing may be very fundamental.  I really means 2000 seconds, the GPU load is just <5%. After i change some setting of the "steps_per_epoch", the GPU loading is around 70%, the speed is much faster but still take >200 seconds to perform the training. is there any way i can know my cuDnn library is installed correct? (apart from running everything without error)